# Redirect to login with add cart button for guest user

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, magento2.3.2

I'm trying to redirect guest users to the login page when they click on the Add to Cart button and they are not registered. But I can't do it. I am using an Observer with the following event

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
```

Below code is for `/app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/event.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="restrict_sales_model_cart_add_before" instance="vendor\module\Observer\ForceLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And below code is for Observer `/app/code/vendor/module/Observer/ForceLogin.php`

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ForceLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $customerSession;
    private $customerUrl;
    private $context;
    private $contextHttp;
    protected $redirect;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $contextHttp,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig     = $scopeConfig;
        $this->context         = $context;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerUrl     = $customerUrl;
        $this->contextHttp     = $contextHttp;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->contextHttp->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

        if (!$isLoggedIn ) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Loggin First.'));
            $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse('200');
            exit();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Any idea why guest users are not redirecting to the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the result redirect. Try this:

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        //session is: \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `addtocart` is using ajax or not

Please refer to my solution

Create a plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add::execute()

File `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::disable_guest_add_to_cart"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\AddPlugin"
                sortOrder="10"
                />
    </type>
</config>
```

File `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Controller/Cart/AddPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;

class AddPlguin
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirect;

    /**
     * @var JsonHelper
     */
    private $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    private $accountRedirect;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $url,
        Session $customerSession,
        RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $refererUrl =  $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
            $route = 'customer/account/login';

            //Redirect after login success
            $this->accountRedirect->setRedirectCookie($refererUrl);
            
            //In case add to cart by submit form
            if(!$subject->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath($route);
            }
           
            //In case add to cart by ajax
            $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
                $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode([
                    'backUrl' => $this->url->getUrl($route)
                ])
            );
            return $subject->getResponse();
        }
        $proceed();
    }
}
```